# struct that holds struct, how to dereference

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

i have couple of linked lists in my larger program which i now want to keep in a struct (t_holder).

```
typedef struct s_list 
{
    int val;
    struct t_list *next;
} t_list;

typedef struct s_holder
{
    t_list  *a_starts;
    // more lists...
}   t_holder;
```

now i try to figure out how i dereference this in my program.

```
void    try_out(t_holder *list_holder, int num)
{
    //assigning something to a_starts
    list_holder->a_starts->val = num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    t_holder    *list_holder;
    int         num;

    num = 42;
    list_holder = NULL;
    try_out(list_holder, num);
    return (0);
}
```

in the function "try_out" i simlpy try to assign a value to a_starts->val but my debugger shows me ACCESS_ERROR if i declare it like this

```
list_holder->a_starts->val = num;
```

Comment: Because you're trying to derefernce a null pointer. First you assign null to it and then you try to deference,  what else could you expect?

Answer (score 0):

For starters this typedef declarations

```
typedef struct s_list 
{
    int val;
    struct t_list *next;  // <===
} t_list;
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
typedef struct s_list 
{
    int val;
    struct s_list *next;  // <===
} t_list;
```

As for your other code then you declared a null pointer

```
t_holder    *list_holder;
//...
list_holder = NULL;
```

So dereferencing the null pointer results in undefined behavior.

You need to write something like the following

```
t_holder    list_holder = { .a_starts = NULL };
//...

try_out( &list_holder, num);
```

and then within the function something like

```
void try_out(t_holder *list_holder, int num)
{
    t_list *node = malloc( sizeof( *node ) );

    node->val = num;
    node->next = list_holder->a_starts;

    list_holder->a_starts = node;
}
```